# Symbols given by Sage of the Six Paths to Naruto and Sasuke Chapter 672

Tags: naruto

In chapter 672 The Sage of the Six Paths engraves one symbol into Naruto and Sasuke:

[image] [image]

Is there any symbolic link to these symbols?

To me it appears as though the symbols are sun and moon, light and darkness.

Also, does it have any connection to Naruto and Sasuke's chakra nature? Naruto's wind element chakra is the promoter for Sasuke's fire element, just like the sun's light makes the moon shine.

Another aspect that hit my eye, is Naruto's symbol is in his right hand, while Sasuke's in his left. The right and left make a perfect set.

So, my question is, is there a link in the symbols given to Naruto and Sasuke. And are these links intentional or unintentional?

Comment: One more possible aspect could be - those 2 being the re-incarnations of Ashura and Indra.

Comment: @R.J Possibly, but again the symbols given to them are similar to their clan symbols, the uchicha clan has a more resemblance than the Uzumaki clan, the senju clan symbol is a lot different.

Comment: Probably a subset kind of thing. The circle can be split into 2 and be represented as a part of Senju clan symbol. Anyways, its purely on speculation for now unless there is more information by Kishimoto.

Comment: First thing it makes me think of. A sun and moon.

Comment: Actually I am about to ask the same question after reading the latest manga chapter. +1.:)

Comment: i guess, it's connected to this whole "ying-yang"-complex

Comment: I mean, symbolic traits are a given, but not for a second will I think it's more than convenient marks for the arms that Naruto and Sasuke will use for their respective final attacks against each other for a super sized page during their fight. They do it in every single one of their fights with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the symbols are **Moon and Sun**, it is very much related to the Symbol Yin Yang.

[image]

The first character yin means: overcast weather; feminine; ***moon***; cloudy; negative electrical charge; shady.

The second character yáng means: positive electrical charge; ***sun***.

The simplified characters clearly show the moon/sun symbolism, since they can be deconstructed to their elements moon and sun. The element is a variant of the radical which means "abundant". So Yin Yang could represent the contrast between the moon and the sun.

But Yin Yang is much more than just a pair of opposites. It conveys the idea that each of the opposites is dependent on the other, and how they continuously transform from one into the other.

Another thing, according to [First Principles: Symbolism of the Sun and Moon](http://www.snowcrest.net/sunrise/apolar1.htm):

Sun can be translated as fixidity, steadiness, firmness, and strength of purpose. The Sun rises day after day regardless of weather conditions, the behavior of humanity or the placement of planets in the sky. It traverses its set path, always giving light and heat and asking nothing for itself in return. Very much like Naruto.

Moon is said to rule the senses and emotions. Moon is said to be fickle and changeable. Emotions change and fluctuate as our thoughts and attitudes change. Synonymous to Sasuke.

## Conclusion:

Naruto and Sasuke (Reincarnation of Indra and Asura) is described to be opposite or contrary with each other but they are interconnected and interdependent naturally; and they give rise to each other as they interrelate to one another.

As per the chakra, well, I think it is also connected (Naruto is Bright Yellow/Light while Sasuke is Dark Violet?/Dark). The nature (wind and fire) is different.

Comment: nice answer.. +1

I'll wait a little longer and see other answers before I accept one. :)

Comment: Yup. I understand. This is merely an analysis with no direct link with neither the manga nor the anime version. But I can edit this if further explained in the next chapters.

Answer (score -2):

I went back and saw this, check out the palms. [image]

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more than just "check out the palms." and an image?

Comment: @kingtimmahb, please could you elaborate on "check the palms"